# Automate the Boring Stuff Chapter 13 - Multiplication Table Maker

Tags: python

The [project outline](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/2e/chapter13/):

> Create a program multiplicationTable.py that takes a number N from the
> command line and creates an N×N multiplication table in an Excel
> spreadsheet.

My solution:

```
# A program to create a NxN multiplication table in excel
# Usage: python multiplication_table_maker.py "number" "folder to save the table in"

import openpyxl, sys
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter, column_index_from_string

def main(num, save_path):
    workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = workbook.active
    for sequence, index in enumerate(range(2, num + 2), 1):
        top = sheet.cell(row=1, column=index).value = sequence
        side = sheet.cell(row=index, column=1).value = sequence
    bottom_right = sheet.cell(row=num + 1, column=num + 1).coordinate
    for rows in sheet["B2":f"{bottom_right}"]:
        for cells in rows:
            top = int(sheet[f"{get_column_letter(cells.column)}1"].value)
            side = int(sheet[f"A{cells.row}"].value)
            cells.value = top * side
    workbook.save(f"{save_path}\multiplication_table_maker.xlsx")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num = int(sys.argv[1])   # Enter a number
    save_path = sys.argv[2]
    main(num, save_path)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`enumerate(range(2, num + 2), 1)` is confusing, consider naming the argument as in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate): `enumerate(range(2, num + 2), start=1)`

The name `sequence` is misleading since it stands for a single number. Same for `rows` and `cells`: should be `row` and `cell`.

```
top = int(sheet[f"{get_column_letter(cells.column)}1"].value)
side = int(sheet[f"A{cells.row}"].value)
```

Here you retrieve values from the excel table. Those values belong to the range you defined a few lines earlier, so just get them from there, it will be faster and more clear.

Answer (score 2):

## enumerate

To me, your `enumerate(...)` is backwards.  Consider for example, a times table where you want only multiples of 3:

```
     3  6  9
   +--------
 3 | 9 18 27
 6 |18 36 54
 9 |27 54 81
```

Your row and column indices would start at 2, and go up by 1.  This is the "enumeration" part.  Your values would start a 3, and go up by 3, which would be the `range()` part.  Ie, `range(3, 10, 3)`.

So instead of:

```
    for sequence, index in enumerate(range(2, num + 2), 1):
```

I would have:

```
    for cell_index, value in enumerate(range(1, num + 1), start=2):
```

This is much clearer: the table values are generated from `1` to `num` (inclusive), and the table row/column indices start at 2.

## save_path

```
    workbook.save(f"{save_path}\multiplication_table_maker.xlsx")
```

Why have you hard-coded the output filename in your function?  Instead, use:

```
    workbook.save(save_path)
```

and let the caller specify the full filename:

```
    main(10, f"{save_path}\10x10.xlsx")
    main(20, f"{save_path}\20x20.xlsx")
    ...
```

## main

Speaking of which, `main(...)` is an utterly undescriptive name.  How about `create_multiplication_table_spreadsheet(...)`?  A bit verbose perhaps, but very clear.

## argparse

Instead of parsing command-line arguments yourself, try using the `argparse` module.